# Vue.js; How do I get local JSON file using Axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm wondering how I wonder how I can read a local JSON file using Axios?`
The data.json file is located in public/info/data.json?
Every time I'm trying to pull off the get request, I'm getting a 404 message

```
Data.json looks like this:
[
{"id": 1239,"name": "Card 1"},
{"id": 1235,"name": "Card 2"},
{"id": 1233,"name": "Card 3"},
{"id": 1233,"name": "Card 4"},
```

]

```
Get method looks like this: 
  created() {
  axios.get("../../public/data/data.json")
  .then((response) => {
      response.data
  })
```

Comment: what are the issues?

Comment: Hi im geting a 404 in the response...

Answer (score 1):

If it's on local, you cannot get it with Axios using path. You can import your local file directly

```
import jsondata from '../your-data.json'
```

Axios only can do network request, so if your json path are on `/public/data.json`. You can request it like this

```
const response = await axios('http://localhost:3000/public/data.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your json into project's public static directory, your json file locates at `~project/public/data/data.json`, request like this

```
axios.get("/data/data.json", {
    baseURL: "/",
  })
```